# Get feed titles from any RSS feed with php

Tags: php, rss

I'm attempting to build an RSS reader at the moment I'm using php's simplexml using 
For example

```
$xml->item->title
```

But however this is dependent on the structure of the rss feed itself if the structure is different it won't work so I was wondering if theres a more broader and less specific way to grab all the titles from a RSS feed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

There is a RSS Specification document out there. You can find it at http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html

Therefore, a RSS file always looks the same, but be carefull. There is always something like Atom.

You could use xPATH for searching within the RSS: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Answer (score 3):

maybe it´s an option for you using a contribution like this instead of invent the wheel again: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3724-PHP-Parse-and-display-items-of-an-RSS-feed.html

Comment: I wouldn't use exactly that, but (for example) the Zend Framework comes with a nice RSS-class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some Regex to filter the RSS files and split them into titles, etc. Whatever you want. As you will define which tags to grab data from.

Using something like: `$regex = '/<(w+)[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>/s';
preg_match_all($reg_exp, $text, $match);`

Comment: Hey, I've used regex once before but I can only seem to target the first occurrence of the <title> tags is there anyway to loop through all the title tags in the file?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can use "preg_match_all()" function instead of "preg_match()". Then use a "foreach" loop to loop through the results.

Comment: Why use RegEx when there are XML-parser's out there to do exactly that... Parsing an XML-file.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of feed formats. Writing code to comply all, is a bit difficult task. so..

I recommend using simple pie. http://simplepie.org/
or you can use [google feed api](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/jsondevguide.html) also. here is a example using simple pie. 
http://simplepie.org/wiki/setup/sample_page